# Ruby and Rails: Show login form content of one view into the another view files modal popup

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to open modal on button click of the `coursedetail.html.erb` the file which is done using a jquery modal.
But now I want to show my login.html.erb file content in this modal so that user will be able to login directly from the `modal` login form.

Comment: Put your login in a partial and render it in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can you `partial` to render the view in rails. To know more about partial click [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)